# jQuery Validation. Как задать rules, чтобы значение select могло быть равно определенному значению?

Tags: jquery, select

Используется плагин jQuery Validation для проверки формы. В форме есть тип поля select (name="city"), в котором список из трех значений: "Выбрать", "Москва", "Санкт-Петербург".
Подскажите, как для city задать rules, чтобы было не равно "Выбрать"?

Answer (score 1):

Для `"Выбрать"` поставьте `value=""` и установите правило `"required"`

[Примерно так](http://jsfiddle.net/mj7kn/)

Comment: mantigatos, спасибо.